# screen size set in Game View does not match the display area in Scene View and Game View. : Unity2D

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

[16:9 portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA2Mr.png)

But screen ratio is not 16:9.
And the left and right sides of the screen are not displayed.

[16:9 Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jmEd.png)

More like a square than 16:9.

[18:9 Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf9c8.png)
[1920x1080 Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QQn8.png)

same as them.

I suspected the camera rotation.
But there was no problem.
Camera rotation was 0 in xyz.

Why?

My enviroments:

- Windows10
- Unity2020, 2021(After I have this problem in 2020, I upgraded 2020 to 2021.)
- build setting: android

Comment: because .... seriously though, it is unclear what `why?` is asking specifically

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.